# Context root "/" set URL to localhost:8080//

Tags: java, server, web-applications, jboss, wildfly

I have a java spring web application running on a local widlfly. Until now it was always the case that I called the webapp via the URL "localhost:8080/myapp". Now I have set my context root in the jboss-web.xml to "/". My assumption would be that I can now call the website via localhost:8080/. But this redirects me to the Widlfly welcome content. I can only call my webapp via "localhost:8080//". Can I set the context root so that I reach the webapp via "localhost:8080"?

Thanks for your help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="10.0"
           xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd">

    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to disable the default welcome app

Comment: You make no mention of having done so https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242941

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. University was very stressful. Everything worked out as described in the link.